# c# how to use webresponseasync method to download web pages'es sources

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a list of web page links, and I need to download their sources. How to use async and await for this?

```
List<string> webpages; //includes web pages links
List<string> sources = new List<string>();
for(i=0, i < webpages.count, i++)
{
  sources.add(async_method_to_download_page_source(webpages[i]))
}
```

Comment: How is `async_method_to_download_page_source` defined?

Comment: i don't know which is faster httpwebrequest or webclient also it depends on which is suitable for async the main point is to download all of the web pages sources as fast as possible so its not defined i need to define it

Comment: Can u help to create this method pls?